# Mobilefirst heartbeat example. Events are not firing

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have imported the example from the below link.

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/data/working-offline/

I have added a WL.Client.connect() in the wlCommonInit()

When i start the application, the control flows in the below order.

```
WL.Logger.debug("I am inside the WL Common Init");  
Registeres the WL.Events.  
WL.Logger.debug("connectDetected called");  
WL.Logger.debug("Inside the connect-onSuccess");
```

But when the setHeartBeatInterval() method is called. Its not calling connectDetected() method agin ?

Can somebody help me understand why its not calling connectDetected() method after calling setHeartBeatInterval() ?

```
function wlCommonInit(){        
    WL.Client.connect({
      onSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
      onFailure: onConnectFailure
    }); 

    function onConnectSuccess() {
        WL.Logger.debug("Inside the connect-onSuccess");
    }

    function onConnectFailure() {
        WL.Logger.debug("Inside the connect-onFailure");
    }

    WL.Logger.debug("I am inside the WL Common Init");  

    document.addEventListener(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED, connectDetected, false); 
    document.addEventListener(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED, disconnectDetected , false);
}

 function connectionFailure(){
    alert("Could not connect to the MobileFirst Server.");
    var output = new Date() + "<hr />Working offline";
    $('#info').html(output); 
 }

 function disconnectDetected(){
    var output = new Date() + "<hr />disconnectDetected";
    $('#info').html(output);
 }

 function connectDetected(){
     WL.Logger.debug("connectDetected called");

     var output = new Date() + "<hr />connectDetected";
     $('#info').html(output);
 }

 function setHeartBeatInterval(interval){
    var output = new Date() + "<hr />heartbeat interval is set to: " + interval;
    $('#info').html(output);
    WL.Client.setHeartBeatInterval(interval);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When do you expect it to call again?
Shut down the server and start it again, it'll detect a connection to the server and then it will get called.

Comment: So when the app is already connected to the server, by calling the setHeartBeatInterval() will not fire the event as the status has not changed ?